# Accessing instances of symbols via Actionscript 3 in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

**Background Information:**

- I am using Adobe Flash CS4
- I am using Actionscript 3
- I am publishing my code into an Adobe AIR document, however I am not sure that this is relevant to this particular problem.
- I've created two symbols in the library, large rectangles, and placed instances of them on the stage.
- I'm using "getObjectsUnderPoint" to detect the objects under where the mouse is clicked.
- I have verified that getObjectsUnderPoint is detecting the symbol instances by tracing the names.

**The Problem**

- The traced names of the objects detected by getObjectsUnderPoint are all instance1, instance2, instance3, etc. even though I have named the instances.
- This causes an issue when trying to ensure that the mouse was clicked on a zone encompassed by either one of the rectangles, as I can't check if object[i].name == "leftbox" , and the instance1, instance2, etc. names change as I add/remove things from the stage, so I do not want to check for instance2 and instance3 (which are as of right now the 2 boxes I've created, which are named "leftbox" and "rightbox" respectively.

**The Question:**

Am I doing something wrong in detecting the names? How do I actually detect the instance names that I have created on the stage through the ActionScript in my class?

**Here is my code:**

```
        var pt:Point = new Point(e.stageX, e.stageY);
        var objects:Array = getObjectsUnderPoint(pt);
        var action = 0;

        for(var i=0; i< objects.length; i++) {
            trace(objects[i].name);
        }

        if( objects.indexOf('left_box') >= 0 ){
            action = 1;

        }
        if(objects.indexOf('right_box') >= 0 ){
            action = 2;

        }
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the getObjectsUnderPoint(pt); function?

Comment: the best I can do is provide you with some documentation, as it is a part of Flash itself:    http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getObjectsUnderPoint()filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#getObjectsUnderPoint()

Comment: SO seems to not allow the link I just posted to function properly, here is a tinyURL that points to the same thing: http://tinyurl.com/44mdase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking forward Fahim Akhter's answer,

You can then loop to get the parent until the object is a movieclip

```
var o:DisplayObject=objects[i];
while(!(o.parent is MovieClip)) {
    o=o.parent;
}
var myMovieClip:MovieClip=o.parent;
```

This should give you a movie clip in myMovieClip and when you trace `myMovieClip.name`, you'll get what you are looking for.

This will also work for multiple level symbols (where 1 symbol contains another)

Comment: I just wrote my own answer, but your solution is more dynamic and re-usable than mine, so I will go ahead and accept yours as the answer. Thanks to Fahim Akhter and you, Pranav Hosangadi

Comment: Pranav, there seems to be an issue with your code. Flash doesn't want to let me assign a DisplayObject to a MovieClip:  var myMovieClip:MovieClip=o.parent; removing ":MovieClip" removes the error, but I'm not sure how good of a fix this is.

Comment: Change that line to `var myMovieClip:MovieClip=o.parent as MovieClip`;

Comment: Removing the :MovieClip just makes myMovieClip an untyped vaariable, so you can assign anything to it. Same as `myMovieClip:Object` or `myMovieClip:*`

Answer (score 1):

Reminds me of a quotation "I do not have the solution to your problem, but I certainly admire the problem"

If you try to trace(objects[i]) you'll see the function getObjectsUnderPoint is returning a shape not the MovieClip, so you never get the name you are looking for.

Comment: Yes this is true (about the Shape vs. MovieClip thing).  Have you any idea how I can get it to return a MovieClip instead of a shape?

Answer (score 1):

Fahim Akhter pointed out in a comment that I was tracing shapes, not objects. This led me to a more accurate google search than I had been able to craft thus far.

The search led me to this forum thread: http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=231181

And in [this](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showpost.php3?p=972880&postcount=6) particular post (number 6), the author pointed out that

> "It turns out that getObjectsUnderPoint returns an array of the
>   simplest object- the child-est, if that makes any sense. I was able to
>   solve part of the problem by simply adding a .parent to the end of my
>   variable..."

I appended .parent to the object, and received the appropriate name:

```
        var pt:Point = new Point(e.stageX, e.stageY);
        var objects:Array = stage.getObjectsUnderPoint(pt);
        var action = 0;

        for(var i=0; i< objects.length; i++) {
            trace(objects[i].parent.name);
        }

        if( objects.indexOf('left_box') >= 0 ){
            action = 1;

        }
        if(objects.indexOf('right_box') >= 0 ){
            action = 2;

        }
```

This solves my problem, and hopefully leads us all to a better understanding of getObjectsUnderPoint.